# Iterating through array angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following a todo list angular tutorial.  Right now, I would like to loop through all of my todo list and clear all of the items where the attribute done is true.

Right now in my index.html file I have a button with the ng-click attribute of "clearCompleted()".  That function looks like this in my js file:

```
$scope.clearCompleted = function () {
  $scope.todos = $filter($scope.todos, function(todo){
    return !todo.done;
  });
};
```

What is wrong with this function because it is not clearing the todo items that are being set to done:true.

And in more of a general question, what is the typical way I could say something along the lines of "select all the items where the attribute done is true" because I am more used to ruby and not javascript.

Comment: I understand that, clearly something in this function is not letting me filter properly.

Comment: Ahh - I misread your code.  No, that does appear to be the right idea.  Sorry, if I were an Angular guy I could likely help.

Comment: Why use $filter at all? Seems like just using Array.filter (or equivalent helper with jQuery or underscore) would be simpler and probably faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax:

`$scope.todos = $filter("filter")($scope.todos, function(todo){`

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/89Qqs/

And don't forget to inject the `$filter` service into controller first!

Answer (score 2):

`$filter(name)`gets the filter with that name. In order to actually call it you can write `$filter(name)(/*arguments for the filter*/)

There is a predefined filter called `filter` that can be used for filtering arrays. You pass in an object for comparisons:

```
$scope.clearCompleted = function () {
    $scope.todos = $filter("filter")($scope.todos, {done:false});
};
```

Which returns all items that have the property `done`with the value `false`.